# Extract data from two different databases using Logstash and Kibana

Tags: sql, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Here is the code from which, I am trying to get the data from the two different databases and passed them to a single event. I have tried some code, but it won't work for me. 
Here is the code.
I have also tried some of the links online

```
input{

  jdbc{
       jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
       jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://mydb1:3306/databasename?useSSL=false"
       jdbc_user => root
       jdbc_password => ******* 
       tracking_column => "updated_at"
       tracking_column_type => timestamp 
       use_column_value => true
       record_last_run => true
       schedule => "*/5 * * * * *"
       clean_run => "${CLEAN_RUN}"
       statement => "SELECT User.id, email, first_name, last_name, updated_at,
                     AuthGroup.id AS group_id, AuthGroup.name AS group_name
                     FROM databasename as User
                     INNER JOIN account_user_groups AS UserGroup
                     ON UserGroup.user_id = User.id
                     INNER JOIN auth_group AS AuthGroup ON AuthGroup.id = UserGroup.group_id"

      jdbc_streaming {
                 jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://mydb2:3306/databasename2?useSSL=false"
                 jdbc_user => root
                 jdbc_password => *******
                 tracking_column => "updated_2_at"
                 tracking_column_type => timestamp
                 use_column_value => true
                 record_last_run => true
                 schedule => "*/5 * * * * *"
                 clean_run => "${CLEAN_RUN}"
                 statement => "SELECT Employee.employee_id as id, Department.id as department_id,
                    Department.name as department_name, Employee.updated_at AS updated_2_at
                    FROM databasename2 AS Employee
                    INNER JOIN departments AS Department on 
                    Employee.department_id=Department.id" 
                    target => "extra"
                    task_id => "%{id}" 
                    add_field => {
                         "id" => "%{[extra][0][id]}"
                         "department_id" => "%{[extra][0][department_id]}"
                         "department_name" => "%{[extra][0][department_name]}"
                         "updated_2_at" => "%{[extra][0][updated_2_at]}"
                   }
                   remove_field => ["extra"] 
            }
      } 
}

     output
     {
      stdout { 
         codec => json
     }
     elasticsearch{
          hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
          document_id => "%{id}"
          index => "users2"
    } 
}
```

The following output that I am looking for:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "email": ****@gmail.com,
  "firstname": Raj,
  "lastname": Kumar,
  "groups": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": SE
  },
  "department": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": DATAGROUP
  }
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: improved code formatting

Comment: At this time , I am getting no output at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is no field or plugin with named jdbc_streaming,try to use two input of jdbc,

```
    input{  
     jdbc{
       jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
       jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://mydb1:3306/databasename?useSSL=false"
       jdbc_user => root
       jdbc_password => ******* 
       tracking_column => "updated_at"
       tracking_column_type => timestamp 
       use_column_value => true
       record_last_run => true
       schedule => "*/5 * * * * *"
       clean_run => "${CLEAN_RUN}"
       statement => "SELECT User.id, email, first_name, last_name, updated_at,
                     AuthGroup.id AS group_id, AuthGroup.name AS group_name
                     FROM databasename as User
                     INNER JOIN account_user_groups AS UserGroup
                     ON UserGroup.user_id = User.id
                     INNER JOIN auth_group AS AuthGroup ON AuthGroup.id = UserGroup.group_id"
}
jdbc {
      jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://mydb2:3306/databasename2?useSSL=false"
      jdbc_user => root
      jdbc_password => *******
      tracking_column => "updated_2_at"
      tracking_column_type => timestamp
      use_column_value => true
      record_last_run => true
      schedule => "*/5 * * * * *"
      clean_run => "${CLEAN_RUN}"
      statement => "SELECT Employee.employee_id as id, Department.id as department_id,
            Department.name as department_name, Employee.updated_at AS updated_2_at
            FROM databasename2 AS Employee
            INNER JOIN departments AS Department on 
            Employee.department_id=Department.id" 
      target => "extra"
      task_id => "%{id}" 
      add_field => {
                         "id" => "%{[extra][0][id]}"
                         "department_id" => "%{[extra][0][department_id]}"
                         "department_name" => "%{[extra][0][department_name]}"
                         "updated_2_at" => "%{[extra][0][updated_2_at]}"
                   }
                   remove_field => ["extra"] 
    }
}

     output
     {
      stdout { 
         codec => json
     }
     elasticsearch{
          hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
          document_id => "%{id}"
          index => "users2"
    } 
}
```